# Setting PartitionCount = NumberOfNodesIntheCluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric, partitioning, service-fabric-stateful

I want to make sure that I am using all the resources (i.e. memory) in the cluster for my stateful partitioned service. However, in ApplicationManifest.xml, I need to set the number of partitions:

```
    <Parameter Name="MyService_PartitionCount" DefaultValue="5" />
```

How can I set this value to the number of nodes available in the cluster? Or at least to a certain ratio of it?

Comment: Changing partitions after they have been set is not a simple task - essentially this cannot change. Consider future load and choose a partition count based on that, not your current node count.  You can have a number of partitions that's higher than the number of nodes - then when you scale the cluster out, service fabric will balance the partitions across the nodes.

Comment: @Oliver I see. Can I still set the number of partitions programmatically based on the node count instead of with a fixed number?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that, doing so would cause problems if the cluster was ever resized later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to represent your app and service via [ARM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-arm-resource) and then use a shared parameter to populate both the partition count and VM count.

There is no specific hint that can be used to indicate that you want a number of partitions equal to the number of nodes, and even if there was then it would not be able to be able to change during runtime as the number of nodes changed.

Generally SF recommends that the choice of the number of partitions be a separate resource/scale calculation. [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-scalability), [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-capacity-planning)